# Reloading URL with GET variable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to reload a page with an appended variable in the URL, deviceID.  It shows up in "realtime" div just fine.  What am I doing wrong?:

```
document.getElementById("realtime").innerHTML = "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(msg)+"</pre>";

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(msg));
        var deviceId = obj.deviceId;

        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        var pathAppend = pathname + "?deviceId=" + deviceId;

            window.location.reload(pathAppend);
```

Comment: provide more code please. Do you want to update the whole page or just a part of it, e.g. a div element? your problem is not clear for me.

Comment: Sorry, I want to reload the whole page!  Added the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using `window.location.reload` incorrectly. `reload` accepts a boolean which:

> when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache. - [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

You should do something like:

```
var query = window.location.search, deviceParam = "deviceId=" + deviceId;

//if there is a query string, append it, otherwise construct the query string.
query += (query === "" ? "?" : "&") + deviceParam;

window.location.search = query; // page should reload
```

Comment: Using this on `http://whatever.com/index?deviceId=500` will duplicate the parameter `http://whatever.com/index?deviceId=500&deviceId=530`